# Book-recommendation: plant biophysics

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, biophysics, book-recommendation

I'm a physicist by training am looking to learn more about the biophysics of plants.

Can you give me your recommendation of good resources on plant biophysics? Books are preferred.

Comment: Seeing that someone voted to close this post, I completely rewrote your post (incl. title and tags). Don't hesitate to switch back if you don't like my edits. Disclaimer: I know nothing about plant biophysics!

Comment: Book recommendation questions are considered 'opinion-based' if specific details are not provided. Please edit your question to add details.

Comment: Plant physiology by Salisbury and Ross, would give you a very good beginning.

Comment: Though some very old (and perhaps forgotten) works; here are 2 volumes of a book by a pioneer of biophysics, J. C. Bose.  Life movements in plants:    1.   http://www.gutenberg.org/files/48280/48280-h/48280-h.htm
  2.     http://www.gutenberg.org/files/40050/40050-h/40050-h.htm

Comment: @Remi.b This question should be kept open like many-other book-recommendation question.

Comment: @WYSIWYG can you please expand on what specific details are missing? To me, the question seems on-topic. 'Plant biophysics' doe snot seem too broad as a subject but I might be mistaken.

Comment: IMO it contains insufficient detail on the users background in bio, the level of book required (high school, undergrad, post grad), and what specific topics need to be covered